# To add cancel button to tab component in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am using tab component (i,e tabs with a custom label template).Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/glydjlanbrm?file=app%2Ftab-group-custom-label-example.ts) link.How can i add cancel button at the top-right corner of the tabs ? I don't want to perform any action with the cancel button,i just need to add the cancel button.
like in below image

[image]

Comment: Just add it into the `ng-template`

Comment: Should i add any icon to `ng-template` ?

Comment: If you want an icon on the cancel button? I'm not really sure what the question is

Comment: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7p7ikc?file=app/tab-group-custom-label-example.html]

Comment: Please see the updated question @user184994

Comment: Take a look at the StackBlitz by @ASakkeer

Comment: I got it, but i need to add material icon(cancel) instead of cancel button.@A.Sakkeer

Comment: I added icon but it is out of the tab can't we add inside the tab?@A.Sakkeer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this, Here i add angular material button as cancel button.

```
    <div class="button-row" style="float:right">
      <button mat-flat-button>Basic</button>
    </div>
```

[Click Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njq3l2?file=app/tab-group-custom-label-example.html)

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7p7ikc-plfdb3)

HTML:

```
<div style="float:left">
    <mat-tab-group style="width:98%;">
        <mat-tab>
            <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon">thumb_up</mat-icon>
                First
            </ng-template>
            Content 1
        </mat-tab>

        <mat-tab>
            <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon">thumb_up</mat-icon>
                Second
            </ng-template>
            Content 2
        </mat-tab>

        <mat-tab>
            <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                <mat-icon class="example-tab-icon">thumb_up</mat-icon>
                Third
            </ng-template>

            Content 3
        </mat-tab>

    </mat-tab-group>
</div>
<div style="width:2%;" style="float-right; ">
    <button style="position:fixed;" mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon >cancel</mat-icon>
  </button>
</div>
```